# C++ template automatic type promotion

Tags: c++, c++03

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
public:
    T val;
    Foo(T _v): val(_v){}
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Foo& A) {
        out << A.val;
        return out;
    }
};

template <class X, class Y> Foo<???> operator+(const Foo<X>& A, const Foo<Y> & B) {
    if (sizeof(X) > sizeof (Y))
        return Foo<X>(A.val + B.val);
    else
        return Foo<Y>(A.val + B.val);
}

int main() {
    Foo<double> a(1.5);
    Foo<int> b(2);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << a+b << endl;
}
```

My goal is to have the `operator+` function to return different type based on types of the arguments.

For example, if `a` is `int` and b is `int` then return `Foo<int>`, if one or both of them are `double` then return `Foo<double>`.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: In response to comments below, I added the tag C++03. When you are tracking a non current version of something you should state that in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible (in C++03 or C++11) using partial template specializations.

```
// C++ does not allow partial specialization of function templates,
// so we're using a class template here.

template <typename X, typename Y, bool xLarger>
struct DoPlusImpl // When x is selected
{
    typedef Foo<X> result_type;
};

template <typename X, typename Y>
struct DoPlusImpl<X, Y, false> // When y is selected
{
    typedef Foo<Y> result_type;
};

template <typename X, typename Y> // Select X or Y based on their size.
struct DoPlus : public DoPlusImpl<X, Y, (sizeof (X) > sizeof (Y))>
{};

// Use template metafunction "DoPlus" to figure out what the type should be.
// (Note no runtime check of sizes, even in nonoptimized builds!)
template <class X, class Y>
typename DoPlus<X, Y>::result_type operator+(const Foo<X>& A, const Foo<Y> & B) {
     return typename DoPlus<X, Y>::result_type
         (A.val + B.val);
}
```

You can see this in action on IDEOne here -> http://ideone.com/5YE3dg

Comment: `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘operator+’ with no type [-fpermissive]`
Is `auto` a feature of C++11?

Comment: @Tran: I confirmed that this is valid -- the trailing return is only necessary for some kind of decltype scenarios. This should do what you want.

Comment: @Tran: Added an IDEOne example working with your sample class.

Answer (score 5):

(C++11): Use a `declval` expression inside dectype:

```
#include <utility>

template <class X, class Y> 
Foo<decltype(std::declval<X>() + std::declval<Y>())> operator+(...);
```

Comment: The compiler says: `‘common_type’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type` and `error: template argument 1 is invalid`

Comment: This time it says `error: ‘declval’ is not a member of ‘std’` and `error: template argument 1 is invalid`

Comment: @TranSonHai Did you include the `<utility>` header?

Comment: A similar solution that doesn't require `std::declval`: `template <class X, class Y> auto operator+(const Foo<X>& A, const Foo<Y> & B) -> Foo<decltype(A.val + B.val)>;`

Comment: I try including <utility> but the error persists.
Anyway I'm not able to compile in C++11, thanks anyway.
` `
@user2093113 `auto` requires C++11 as well.

Comment: @Tran: `decltype` also requires C++11.

Comment: @TranSonHai Use the compiler option `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I mean it's impossible for me to compile in C++11 because my platform (JNI on Android) does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ! Here is the way if you want to give your own rules:

```
template <typename X, typename Y> struct Rule {};
template<> struct Rule<int, int> { typedef int type;};
template<> struct Rule<float, int> { typedef bool type;};
```

Then

```
template <class X, class Y> Foo<typename Rule<X, Y>::type> operator+(...)
```

Comment: Could you make it more generic?, say Foo could take not only int, double, float but a whole bunch of different types, do it your way will result in n^2 possible combinations.

Comment: This doesn't work unless the OP knows the universe of all types X and Y, and requires the OP to provide explicit specializations for reverses. (That is, one needs to define an explicit specialization for `<int, double>` and `<double, int>`) Presumably the OP does not know what all values of `X` and `Y` are.